# Is there a standard way to generate a RESTful access token?

Tags: rest, authorization, access-token

I just touch with RESTful API. Basically, no matter what the rest api is, the first step is to get access token. However, I have been in two different situations:

1. Have client_ID, Client_secret, and username, password.

   ```
   POST: api.XX.com/1/authorize?
         Authorization:Basic [client_id:client_secret] must be base 64 encoded
         Content-Type: application/json
   ```

   Then, I get access token without timeout.
2. Have app_key

   ```
   GET https://api.XX.com/authorize?
       response_type=Pin&
       client_id=APP_KEY&
       scope=SCOPE
   ```

   After get Pin, register in web application. Then use code to request access token.

   ```
   POST https://api.XX.com/token?
       grant_type=Pin&
       code=AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN&
       client_id=APP_KEY
   ```

Finally, I have access token and reflesh token. access token will be timeout after 1hr.
So I need to use refresh token application access again.

I just want to say, Even the RESTful doesn't have Standard, access token application methods are big different. I think the first one is better. The first one makes things simple.

Because I just start to call RESTful Web Services, I would ask:
     Are these two authorization methods common way? Is there a third method to get access token? Any comments please. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a question in this

Comment: 'no matter what the rest api is, the first step is to get access token.' That is false. REST has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: Hi Tichodroma, OH really? I just start to learn it. What I mentioned above is what I know now. However, I really want to hear your guys advice. I got wrong, so I need to do more research.

Comment: Hi Kristian, I just demonstrate what I learned from REST. Wish you can give me suggestion. I suppose it not question, more like a share what I learn. but probably I am wrong in some part. Thank you for focusing on my post.

Comment: Eric, please rephrase your post to be in question form, otherwise it will be closed by the moderators as "off topic"

Comment: Kristian, Thank you for your remind. I wish this post can make authorization more clear. Then I am going to find the way how to implement it in code level, probably using Jersey Client API.